# C++ iconv from utf-16 to utf-8

Tags: iconv, utf-8, c++, linux

Код

```
size_t roleBaseNameLenUTF16 = cuint::Uncompress(buf, &pos);
size_t roleBaseNameLenUTF8 = roleBaseNameLenUTF16;
char* roleBaseNameUTF16 =  new char[roleBaseNameLenUTF16+2];
char* roleBaseNameUTF8 =  new char[roleBaseNameLenUTF8+2];
memcpy(roleBaseNameUTF16, &buf[pos], roleBaseNameLenUTF16);

iconv_t conv = iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE");
iconv(conv, &roleBaseNameUTF16, &roleBaseNameLenUTF16, &roleBaseNameUTF8, &roleBaseNameLenUTF8);
iconv_close(conv);
```

После конвертирования в roleBaseNameUTF8 одни нули (0х00);
В roleBaseNameUTF16 до конвертирования строка OneShoteR в UTF-16LE.

Вот побайтовый вывод roleBaseNameUTF16

```
4F006E006500530068006F00740065005200
```

а вот вывод roleBaseNameUTF8

```
000000000000000000
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Kenpachi](/users/2807/kenpachi), попробовал и у меня получилось. Возможно Вы печатаете результат (utf-8), как-то базируясь на возвращаемом `iconv()` значении. Возвращается 0 и это нормально.

Вот на скорую руку попробовал Ваш пример

```
~/Рабочий стол/avp/hashcode $ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l

~/Рабочий стол/avp/hashcode $ cat icvutf8-16.c 
// icvutf8-16.c  iconv() to utf8 from utf16
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iconv.h>

int
hchar (int h)
{
  h = toupper(h);
  if ('0' <=  h && h <= '9')
    return h-'0';
  return h-'A'+10;
}

int
hstr (char *hex, char *res)
{
  int l = 0;

  while (*hex) {
    int c1 = hchar(*hex++),
      c2 = hchar(*hex++);
    *res++ = (c1<<4)|c2;
    l++;
  }
  *res++ = 0;
  *res = 0;
  return l;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char utf16[100], *p = utf16;

  size_t lutf16 = hstr("4F006E006500530068006F00740065005200",utf16),
    lutf8;
#if DEBUG
  while (*p || *(p+1)) {
    int i = *p++;
    printf ("%x\n",i);
  }
  printf ("lutf16 = %d\n",lutf16);
#endif

  char utf8[lutf8 = (lutf16+=2)];
  iconv_t ic = iconv_open("utf-8","utf16le");
  if (ic == (iconv_t)-1)
    perror("iconv");
  char *ut16 = utf16, *ut8 = utf8;

  printf ("before iconv lutf16 = %ld, lutf8 = %ld\n",
      lutf16, lutf8);
  size_t lres = iconv(ic,&ut16,&lutf16,&ut8,&lutf8);
  printf ("lres = %ld, lutf16 = %ld, lutf8 = %ld\n"
      "utf8 = [%s]\n",
      lres, lutf16, lutf8, utf8);
}
~/Рабочий стол/avp/hashcode $ 
~/Рабочий стол/avp/hashcode $ gcc icvutf8-16.c 
~/Рабочий стол/avp/hashcode $ ./a.out
before iconv lutf16 = 20, lutf8 = 20
lres = 0, lutf16 = 0, lutf8 = 10
utf8 = [OneShoteR]
~/Рабочий стол/avp/hashcode $ 
~/Рабочий стол/avp/hashcode $ iconv --version
iconv (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.3) 2.15
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.
~/Рабочий стол/avp/hashcode $
```

Т.е. у меня все перекодируется, в буфер с utf-8 заносятся 10 байт (включая завершающий 0).

У Вас ОС какая?

Comment: OS Ubuntu 12lte или как там её.
Попробовал ваш пример, действительно все работает.
У меня Iconv тоже возвращает что все выполнено успешно, завтра уже буду сравнивать ваш код с моим, а пока огромное спасибо вам. Ещё отпишусь =)