# Вопрос по кодировкам в с++

Tags: кодировка, c++, linux

Подскажите как под Linux в С++ преобразовывать из одной кодировки в другую. К примеру из cp1251 в utf8 и наоборот.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Есть такая библиотека - iconv, идет в стандартных пакетах большинства дистрибутивов. Умеет переводить кодировки в разных направлениях. Как пример кода нашел [это](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/464494).

Еще примеры:

- [C++ iconv from utf-16 to utf-8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/183033/linux-c-iconv-from-utf-16-to-utf-8)
- http://www.metashock.de/2011/01/basic-iconv-example-in-c/
- http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/iconv_c.txt.html

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь) Вы меня просто спасаете)